# How can you prevent a user from changing time and date settings on an android tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

How can you prevent a user from changing time and date settings on an android tablet?
Is there a programmatic way to do this.
Can this be done remotely. 
The solution must either be able to enforce an internet connection / or be enforced at a hardware level to prevent the user from changing the time and date.

Comment: not without some custom rom

Comment: You could block the access of the settings screen.

Comment: Do you need to prevent the date and time for being changed? Or any secure way to save current date and time, even offline? If your case is the second, I have asked a new question in hope to find a answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/47265996/3424212